# Can't copy from PDF file generated from UWP app

Tags: xaml, pdf, printing, uwp, uwp-xaml

I'm trying to print from UWP app and following this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/devices-sensors/print-from-your-app)

While saving it as a pdf file, it's printing normally. I'm able to copy the letters as well. But when I'm pasting it somewhere else, it is printing something like this: ""

I've tried different fonts as well, but no help.

Here is the XAML I'm trying to print:

```
    <Grid x:Name="PrintableArea" Background="White">
        <StackPanel x:Name="TextContent">
            <TextBlock TextAlignment="Center" FontFamily="Arial" FontWeight="Bold">
                        This is Test
            </TextBlock >
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
```

How to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whatever you are using to create the PDF is clearly unable to create the PDF file with a ToUnicode CMap.

PDF files usually only embed a subset of a font in order to keep the size down. This generally means that the Encoding applied to the font is non-standard (and it generally isn't ASCII anyway). So for example if you have the text "Hello World" then the character codes would be assigned so that "H" = 1, "e" = 2 and so on.

If you copy and paste that, then you get 1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 6, 4, 7, 3, 8 which will appear as binary.

A PDF file may contain a ToUnicode CMap which maps the character code to Unicode code points, and a PDF viewer application can use that to copy the Unicode code points instead of the character codes, which permits sane copy/paste. But its optional. This is because the original design decisions around PDF were to create a portable **viewer**, the PDF file should look the same on all consumers, but the designers didn't have editing or copying in mind.

Comment: Actually, I am getting the pdf correct, no issue with its content or orientation at all. I'm not able to copy the content. I discussed with an iOS developer, he said that even the pdf file generated by them is also non-copyable.

Comment: I didn't mention its orientation or visible appearance. I'm talking about the internals of your PDF file; what's actually in the file as opposed to what you see when you render it to a display. Instead of the text being (for example) 0x48, 0x65, 0x6c, 0x6c, 0x6F etc, what's in the file is 0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x03, 0x04. Now if you copy and paste the first set of numbers, you'll get 'Hello' because its ASCII and most applications will assume that it is. If you copy the second you'll get a bunch of binary. Your only solution is to make the PDF a more sophisticated way.

Comment: Ok, I think I got it. I'll try it accordingly. Thanks.